# Can we print php var from jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

In php I have this:

```
'posts_per_page' => 6,
```

I need to be able to generate that number `6` from jquery. LIterally Based on a screen resolution, I need to generate the number of posts I want to display. I know I can check the screen resolution and size with jquery but how do I output a variable lets say `<?php $postNumber ?>` from lets say a jquery variable? So that I could have

```
'posts_per_page' => <?php echo $postNumber ?>,
```

Comment: `<?php $postNumber ?>` is not doing anything, make it: `<?php echo $postNumber ?>` and youre fine.

Comment: how are you passing 6 to php page?

Comment: @John sorry yes, that wasn't the main issue here tho. Edited the question.

Comment: @BhushanFirake nope exactly, I don't know how to pass it

Comment: You have flaws in your design: php acts server-side, while javascripts acts client-side. You should either delegate your layout fully client-side (using JS / JQuery) or by passing JS variables to server using AJAX / posts, then reloading / updating (parts of) the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the screen resolution in jquery as below:

```
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
```

and you can set the number of posts acccording to the resolution.Say number of posts is 6.

```
var noOfPosts=6;
```

Now , you will need to post this data to the php page as below using AJAx

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: page.php,//the page to which you want to send data
  data: postNumber=noOfPosts,
  success: function(){print("success");}
});
```

you can retrieve this number 6 on php pagee as below:

```
  $postNumber= $_POST["postNumber"];
```

and then use it as you want.

**EDIT**:

So , you will have to keep it whole as below:

```
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
var noOfPosts=0;//Default no of posts you want to have
if(browserWidth<960)
{
    noOfPosts=3;
}
```

The AJAX call will be the same but it will be after this code block.

:

Comment: Ah! That's like.. done! :) In this case I could say: if (browserWidth < 960 ) { var noOfPosts=3; } ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the screen resolution with jQuery and pass it to PHP? If yes, you'll need to use Ajax.
Example with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'page.php',
    data: {screenSize: 6},
}).done(function(data){

}).fail(function(error){

});
```

Comment: The page.php will receive the variable you passed. If you want, you can return HTML from it and append the HTML on the page.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot like that. Javascript is executed on the client browser while php is executed on the server machine. To comunicate between client and server you should make an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

According to you, your first code block *is* PHP. Thus there is no need to switch into PHP mode with the PHP embedding tag, `<?php`, nor to echo (as shown in your second code block).

If `$postNumber` contains the value you want then

```
'posts_per_page' => 6,
```

simply becomes

```
'posts_per_page' => $postNumber,
```

Comment: yes, it's a perfect correction to my question code. BUt seriously, it was just a wrongly quick typo. The issue wasn't that but you are right.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, then, please?

Comment: need to pass a jquery var to a php var. The answers below are quite clear, the issue is client vs server side. Ajax is the solution.

Comment: But you need to clarify the question so that the answer fits it. I am not asking for my sake, but for the sake of how SO works and the myriad of Google users who land on a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to write javascript which contains the variable you need.

Comment: well but If i use jquery to calculate and detect screen resolution then I will need to be able to print whatever jquery var to php. SO, unless I didn't understand you, I think I need the opposite no?

Comment: Aha--yes, I misread you, it is clearer now after the first edit you made. Fonini has you better-covered.